# How to sniff a network interface with Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted, scapy, packet-sniffers

I need to receive raw packets from a network interface within Twisted code. The packets will not have the correct IP or MAC address, nor valid headers, so I need the raw thing.

I have tried looking into `twisted.pair`, but I was not able to figure out how to use it to get at the raw interface.

Normally, I would use `scapy.all.sniff`. However, that is blocking, so I can't just use it with Twisted. (I also cannot use `scapy.all.sniff` with a timeout and busy-loop, because I don't want to lose packets.)

A possible solution would be to run `scapy.all.sniff` in a thread and somehow call back into Twisted when I get a packet. This seems a bit inelegant (and also, I don't know how to do it because I am a Twisted beginner), but I might settle for that if I don't find anything better.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could run a distributed system and pass the data through a central queuing system. Take the Unix philosophy and create a single application that does a few tasks and does them well. Create one application that sniffs the packets (you can use `scapy` here since it won't really matter if you block anything) then sends them to a queue (RabitMQ, Redis, SQS, etc) and have another application process the packet from the queue. This method should give you the least amount of headache.

If you need to run everything in a single application, then threads/multiprocessing is the only option. But there are some design patterns you'll want to follow. You can also break up the following code into separate functions and use a dedicated queuing system.

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
from twisted.internet import defer, reactor

class Sniffer(Thread):
    def __init__(self, _reactor, shared_queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.reactor = _reactor
        self.shared_queue = shared_queue

    def run(self):
        """
        Sniffer logic here
        """
        while True:
            self.reactor.callFromThread(self.shared_queue.put, 'hello world')
            sleep(5)

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def consume_from_queue(_id, _reactor, shared_queue):
    item = yield shared_queue.get()
    print(str(_id), item)
    _reactor.callLater(0, consume_from_queue, _id, _reactor, shared_queue)

def main():
    shared_queue = defer.DeferredQueue()
    sniffer = Sniffer(reactor, shared_queue)
    sniffer.daemon = True
    sniffer.start()

    workers = 4
    for i in range(workers):
        consume_from_queue(i+1, reactor, shared_queue)

    reactor.run()

main()
```

The `Sniffer` class starts outside of Twisted's control. Notice the `sniffer.daemon = True`, this is so that the thread will stop when the main thread has stopped. If it were set to `False` (default) then the application will exit only if all the threads have come to an end. Depending on the task at hand this may or may not always be possible. If you can take breaks from sniffing to check a thread event, then you might be able to stop the thread in a safer way.

`self.reactor.callFromThread(self.shared_queue.put, 'hello world')` is necessary so that the item being put into the queue happens in the main reactor thread as opposed to the thread the `Sniffer` executes. The main benefit of this would be that there would be some sort of synchronization of the messages coming from the threads (assuming you plan to scale to sniffing multiple interfaces). Also, I wasn't sure of `DeferredQueue` objects are thread safe :) I treated them like they were not.

Since Twisted isn't managing the threads in this case, it's vital that the developer does. Notice the `worker` loop and `consume_from_queue(i+1, reactor, shared_queue)`. This loop ensures only the desired number of workers are handling tasks. Inside the `consume_from_queue()` function, `shared_queue.get()` will wait (non-blocking) until an item is put into the queue, prints the item, then schedule another `consume_from_queue()`.

Comment: Thank you! This is a quick&dirty hack, so a distributed solution would be waaaay overkill. I will probably go with your shared queue approach, then. Thank you very much!